# C# - Creating BMP from Bytes

Tags: c#, bmp, lockbits

I'm creating a WinForm Application in C# that I can use to "sniff out" some 24 bit bitmaps in a file. I already gathered information such as its offset, some analysis on how it is written in the file, and its length.

So more information about the file are:

- The BMP data is written reversely. (Example : (255 0 0) is written (0 0 255)
- It has no BMP header. Only chunks of BMP's image data.
- PixelFormat is 24 bit.
- Its BMP is pure magenta. (255 0 255 in RGB)

I'm using the following code :

```
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\MyFile.exe", FileMode.Open))
            {
                    int width = 190;
                    int height = 219;
                    int StartOffset = 333333;   // Just a sample offset

                    Bitmap tmp_bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, tmp_bitmap.Width, tmp_bitmap.Height);
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                        tmp_bitmap.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                        tmp_bitmap.PixelFormat);

                    unsafe
                    {
                        // Get address of first pixel on bitmap.
                        byte* ptr = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;

                        int bytes = width * height * 3; //124830 [Total Length from 190x219 24 Bit Bitmap]

                        int b;  // Individual Byte

                        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
                        {
                            fs.Position = StartOffset - i;  // Change the fs' Position [Subtract since I'm reading in reverse]
                            b = fs.ReadByte();              // Reads one byte from its position

                            *ptr = Convert.ToByte(b);   // Record byte
                            ptr ++;
                        }
                        // Unlock the bits.
                        tmp_bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                    }
                    pictureBox1.Image =  tmp_bitmap;
                }
```

I get this output. I think the reason is that the bytes are getting messed up whenever it hit the next line. (255 0 255 becomes 0 255 255 and it goes on until it becomes 255 255 0)

[image: Output]

I hope you can help me fix this. Thank you very much in advance.

**SOLUTION**
Now it is fixed by adding this code (with some help from my friend and information given by James Holderness)

```
if (width % 4 != 0)
    if ((i + 1) % (width * 3) == 0 && (i + 1) * 3 % width < width - 1)
         ptr += 2;
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess the problem is you don't use bmpData.Stride in your code , in bitmap data pixels placed in a line are following each other but when changing the line there might be some other data which doesn't belong to pixels so everything goes wrong , I'll post an answer for this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a standard BMP, each individual scan line needs to be a multiple of 4 bytes, so when you have a 24 bit image (3 bytes per pixel), you often need to allow for padding at the end of every scan line to bring it up to a multiple of 4.

For example, if your width if 150 pixels, that's 450 bytes, which needs to be rounded up to 452 to make it a multiple of 4.

I suspect that might be the problem you're having here.